# sharing immutable files between android apps

Tags: android, file, share, zip, bytebuffer

I have written 2 apps, whose data is downloaded from the internet.

As this data (around 40Mb, in a few zip files) is the same, I would like to share it between the 2 apps so that it consumes less bandwith and less storage space for the user.

At the moment, I haven't found a good solution :

- Originaly, I saved the data in the public download directory. 
  This is a simple solution but it requires read permission and I want to avoid that.
- Then I thought that I could use Content providers (and inputStreams and mmaped ByteBuffers) but, at the core, my apps put many zip files
  in a big ZipResourceFile where :
  some compressed files are read and copied
  some uncompressed files are mmaped and used as a lucene database

So, I can forget about a simple FileProvider as I need a File to get a ZipFile in order to uncompress my data

Also, It may be possible to build a ZipFileProvider, where my files would be put in a big ZipResourceFile whose part would be served through a content provider, like this library does :
https://github.com/jarondl/android-zipfileprovider/blob/master/src/net/jarondl/zipfileprovider/ZipFileProvider.java

But, if I get some mmaped ByteBuffer through such a ZipFileContentProvider, Will it be able to have a long and safe life ? (Should I use a Service ?)
What if the process of the ZipFileContentProvider that served it died ? 
What about memory consumtion ? What are the caveats ? 
Aren't ContentProvider supposed to be used in a short-life way ?

Is there a better solution ?

UPDATE :

It really sucks that android can't share a directory for a few apps from the same developper (**and noone else**). Or is it possible ?

UPDATE2:

I considered storing the files on the getExternalFilesDir(), but the following official warning is making me extremely nervous (what about writing ?):

> Caution Although the directories provided by getExternalFilesDir() and
>   getExternalFilesDirs() are not accessible by the MediaStore content
>   provider, other apps with the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission can
>   access all files on the external storage, including these. If you need
>   to completely restrict access for your files, you should instead write
>   your files to the internal storage.

Comment: Can't you use ZipInputStream wrapping InputStream opened from ContentResolver?

Comment: Hadn't thought about that. The performance compared to ZipFileProvider should be horrible though when you have to traverse the whole file to get to read the last zipEntry...

Answer (score 1):

> It really sucks that android can't share a directory for a few apps from the same developper. Or is it possible ?

You state prior to this that its possible, but you are trying to avoid it

> Originaly, I saved the data in the public download directory. This is a simple solution but it requires read permission and I want to avoid that.

There is nothing wrong with using the read permission. or write permission for that matter. Is there any specific reason you wish to avoid it?

Add read /write permissions where appropriate to your two apps, and access your own re-used folder structure. It doesn't have to be the public download directory.  e.g. `<com.MyCompanyNamespace>/Data`

Then you could:

1. Check your folder
2. Else check public folder and move to your folder.
3. Else direct to the download site.

There is nothing wrong with using read/write perimssions. And you can state on the app store or in app, as to why the permissions are needed, to ease their minds.

I know you had loads more questions, but hopefully this simple answer removes the need.

Comment: 1) money : some users avoid apps that ask permissions
2) security : what if a malicious app with read/write permission access my files on external storage (say getExternalFilesDir()) and subtly tampers with them (so that the app crashes sometimes) ?

Comment: @Lakedaemon While i agree on point 1, this is a small percentage to which most, if not all can be re-assured by specifying prior to installation what the permission is used for. Aka storing share files between apps. Does not read any other data from device. (specified above) 2. Then you have hit the other audience that doesn't read permissions at all. It is acceptably beyond your control. But should consider, that if such were to happen, it would have to have targetted Every file (unlikely to be specific). To which all apps/device would be affected. Your app would unlikely be blamed.

Comment: if each app writes data in getExternalFileDirs() and ask for the read Permission to access the data of other apps, it indeed provides the best of class performance with requiring the single read permission as a trade off.
If no better solution appears, I'll accept your answer.